# absolute position divs within Jscrollpane

Tags: javascript, jquery, jscrollpane

There appears to be a fundamental problem with Jscrollpane. The vertical scroll does not work when there is an absolute position div inside the scrollpane.
This is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){  

$('#test').jScrollPane({showArrows: true,
    verticalArrowPositions: 'split',
    horizontalArrowPositions: 'split',
    autoReintialise: true
    });

});
</script>

<div id="test" style="width:600px; height:500px">

  <div style="width:400px;height:1200px;border:1px solid #000;position:absolute">
            test test test</div>
  </div>
```

How can I make this work with an absolute positioned div?